# Rails: is it bad practice to call methods in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

Is it bad practice to do this in a view (it's a helper method)?

```
<% get_articles %>
```

If so, where should it live? It seems logical to me to call them in their corresponding controller blocks, but I'm not sure if that's correct or how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the method lives in a helper, its designed to be called in the view.  Really depends on what that method is doing if it should be there.

Is it accessing the database?  If so, it should be called from the controller and its results stored in a variable to be used by the view.  (It also shouldn't be in a helper).

If that method simply generates html to be used in the view, then you would output it as

```
<%= get_articles %>
```

Comment: It is accessing the database, yeah. So nothing accessing the database should live in the helper? Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Separation of concerns/Single Responsibility Principle -- the view layer should be responsible for laying out the view and that's all.

Comment: Exactly, Views are responsible for layout / display.

Controllers access models methods to get data the views need / handle routing logic.

Answer (score 0):

No, helper methods are for views. so its not wrong if you call a helper method in your view. Take a look at this [post](http://techspry.com/ruby_and_rails/designing-helpers-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: If the helper method does things that don't belong in the view (such as fetching data from ActiveRecord), it's just as bad.

Comment: This, but what is `get_articles` doing? It doesn't sound like something that should be a helper method.

Comment: It's accessing the database to collect some records.

Comment: If it is not common task in all the views then you pass the data form controller into the view directly. Database queries should not live in helpers because they are not ment for that. Helpers are used to do some common task across views. For example to check if a particular condition is true of false, you won't write the logic every time in your view. just create a helper method and call it in the views.

Comment: Accessing the database should definitely *not* be done in helpers or views. This is what your controller is for.